# WriteHtml Can't Work Properly in mpdf send mail with attachment in php mvc?

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, mpdf

I tried to make pdf from html from mpdf library and send mail with pdf file attachment.but i can't. WriteHtml Can't Responced.

WriteHtml Give Response :

```
Headers no-store no-chach type:html/text
$mpdf = $StockModel->getPdfObj();
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'ISO-8859-2';       
//$mpdf->allow_html_optional_endtags = true;
//$mpdf->restoreBlockPageBreaks = true; 
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;   
//$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print')); 
$mpdf->SetHeader('|'.$stype.'|Date '.date("d-M-Y").' ');
$mpdf->SetFooter('www.angellogistic.in');
$mpdf->defaultheaderfontsize=7;
$mpdf->defaultheaderfontstyle='B';
$mpdf->defaultheaderline=0;
$mpdf->defaultfooterfontsize=7;
$mpdf->defaultfooterfontstyle='BI';
$mpdf->defaultfooterline=0;
$mpdf->SetTitle("angel logistic");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("angel logistic");
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText("angel logistic");
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
```

In html Assign html and inline css code and tags.

Comment: Why do you set input charset to ISO-8859-2 and then encode html to UTF8? What is the exact output? Any errors in logs? What happens when you set `$mpdf->debug = true;`?